# Counting the number of solution for the next inequality

Tags: combinatorics

How many series of $t$  integer numbers $(x_1,x_2,...,x_t)$, such that $\left|x_1\right|\le n$, and for each $1\le i \le t$ there exist $\left|x_{i+1}-x_{i}\right|\le n$, there are?

---

$\textbf{My attempt}$: by the given information we have - $-n\le x_1 \le n$. Also, we have that $-n\le x_2-x_1\le n$ which implies $-n+x_1\le x_2 \le n+x_1$ so we have found that $-2n\le x_2\le 2n$, and so on... Now we by summing all elements of the series, we have the next inequality: $-tn...-2n-n\le x_1+x_2+...+x_t\le n+2n+...+tn$, therefore: $$\left|x_1+x_2+...+x_t \right|\le \sum_{i=1}^{t}{i\cdot n}$$
Now, I don't know how to proceed.I will be glad to get some help from you. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: How many choices do you have for $x_1$? Once you have chosen $x_1$, how many choices do you have for $x_2$? Does it depend on what $x_1$ was? Continue with $x_3$, then $x_4$, etc.

Comment: It seems you can choose $x_1$ in $2n+1$ different ways, and however you choose it, you have $2n+1$ choices for $x_2$, and so on. The number of choices in each step is therefore independent of previous choices. In this case, do you know of a principle that can be applied?

Comment: @MikeEarnest it depends on what we chose no?

Comment: @primes.against.humanity I don't get it. How the precious choices don't affect?

Comment: For example, if $n=2$, there are $5$ possibilities for $x_1:\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. Suppose $x_1=1$. Then there are $5$ numbers satisfying $|x_2-1|\le 2$ (what are they?). Similarly, if $x_1=2$, there are still five numbers satisfying $|x_2-2|\le 2$. Keep exploring this pattern until you understand its reason.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretend you had a sorted list of all such sequences.  This list starts with a block of sequences starting $(-n, \dots)$ and ends with a  block of sequences starting $(n, \dots)$.  So there are $2n+1$ blocks, organized by value of $x_1$.  In the language of combinatorics, there are $2n+1$ choices for $x_1$.

In that first block, we start with
$$  (-n, -2n, \dots )  $$
and end with
$$  (-n, 0, \dots )  \text{.}  $$
In a generic block, we start with
$$  (x_1, x_1 -n, \dots)  $$
and end with
$$  (x_1, x_1 +n, \dots)  \text{.}  $$
That is, (for any choice of $x_1$) there are $2n+1$ choices for $x_2$.

It should be clear that these have sub-blocks exhibiting $2n+1$ choices for $x_3$ (for any choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$) and sub-sub-blocks exhibiting $2n+1$ choices for $x_4$ and so on for the subsequent $x_i$ for $4 < i \leq t$.

I agree that the particular range of choices of $x_2$ depends on $x_1$ and the particular range of choices of $x_3$ depends on $x_1$ and $x_2$ and, generally, the particular range of choices of $x_n$ depends on $x_i$ for all $1 \leq i < n$.  But, regardless of the particular range of choices, there are always $2n+1$ choices in that range.  So each $x_i$ is chosen from an interval containing $2n+1$ integers.

Therefore, the number of such sequences is
$$ (2n+1)^t  \text{.}  $$